# How to select sound device to play sounds?

Tags: c#, .net, audio, naudio, directsound

I have a webbrowser in my form, I want to choose where I want to listen the sounds.
I have 2 playback devices, Speakers and Headphones.

I want to make a combobox to select the output of the sounds of my form/app.

I was reading about NAudio and DirectSound, but I cant find something usefull.

I don't want to play a sound, I want to select the output of all the sounds of my controls.

Anyone knows something about this for .Net (c#)?

Comment: nothing to show... really.

Comment: The NAudio demo app shows how to do this with WaveOut, DirectSound, WASAPI and ASIO, each of which maintain their own list of devices.

Answer (score 0):

Check [CoreAudioAPI](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18520/Vista-Core-Audio-API-Master-Volume-Control)

You can enumerate the available list of audio devices using

```
MMDeviceEnumerator devEnum = new MMDeviceEnumerator();
```